# Flexslider not working in html site (jQuery not loading?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I somehow broke my Flexslider galleries: first image loads, but no navigation buttons and no animation.

Here's [my site](http://www.esthergibbons.com)

By loading an old html gallery and testing, I can see that the problem is not within the HTML, since the old page also now displays a broken gallery.

This means the problem is with the js file or with the css style file?

I went through the old and new versions of the js file and everything seems unchanged.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Here is the part that calls the js:

```
<!-- CSS================================================== -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.esthergibbons.com/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.esthergibbons.com/css/colors/cyan.css" id="colors">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Java Script
================================================== -->
<script src="http://www.esthergibbons.com/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.esthergibbons.com/scripts/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.esthergibbons.com/scripts/jquery.selectnav.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.esthergibbons.com/scripts/jquery.twitter.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.esthergibbons.com/scripts/jquery.modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.esthergibbons.com/scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.esthergibbons.com/scripts/jquery.contact.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.esthergibbons.com/scripts/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.esthergibbons.com/scripts/jquery.jcarousel.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.esthergibbons.com/scripts/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.esthergibbons.com/scripts/jquery.layerslider.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.esthergibbons.com/scripts/jquery.shop.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.esthergibbons.com/scripts/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your `<script src="http://www.esthergibbons.com/scripts/custom.js"></script>` script looks like this at the top:

`(function($){
 $(document).ready(function(){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see that you are calling the `.flexslider` function.

You need to place this in your custom.js file.

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide"
});
```

Comment: This solution worked! Thanks. Can I ask if there's someplace else this function could be called? Because I didn't touch the custom.js file during the time I broke the flexslider... so I guess I deleted the "call the function" action somewhere else in code?

Comment: Im not sure. You can do a find on your old source code